# additivity of elements in Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

When I was learning the interaction picture of the Hamiltonian, the usual way to convert it from the Schrodinger picture is using the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula,
\begin{equation}
e^ABe^{-A}=B+[A,B]+\frac{1}{2!}[A,[A,B]]+\ldots.
\end{equation}
I am wondering if $A$ and $B$ can be separated to several parts, say $A=A_1+A_2$ and $B=B_1+B_2+B_3$, how the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula looks like. I guess it should be like
\begin{equation}
e^A(B_1+B_2+B_3)e^{-A}=e^{A_2}e^{A_1}B_1e^{-A_1}e^{-A_2}+e^{A_2}e^{A_1}B_2e^{-A_1}e^{-A_2}+e^{A_2}e^{A_1}B_3e^{-A_1}e^{-A_2}.
\end{equation}
I am a physicist. May I ask whether this is mathematically true?

Thank you!

Comment: In general, $\exp(A+A')$ is not the same as $\exp(A)\exp(A')$, so what you guess is not correct. In fact, the BCH formula is **precisely** a measure of why those two things are not equal.

Comment: Your formula is valid only if $[A_1,A_2]=[B_1,B_2]=...=0$

Comment: @Andrei you don't need to impose the B commutations.

Comment: Thanks @AHusain. You are right

Comment: Thank you guys. So, $e^A (B+B')e^{-A}=e^A Be^{-A}+e^A B'e^{-A}$ is still valid, right?

Comment: Of course. The expression is linear. BTW, what you write is a straightforward [lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma_and_its_application_to_a_special_case_of_the_Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff_formula), often dubbed "the Hadamard lemma", but *not* the mainstream CBH formula.